# Let $T$ be a contraction in a Hilbert space $H$. If $\| T^n x\| \to 0$ for $n \to \infty$, does $\| (c \cdot T)^n x \| \to 0$, where $c > 1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, contraction-operator

The obvious problem here is that because $c > 1$, then $c^n \to \infty$ for $n \to \infty$. So we have:

$$\| (c \cdot T)^n x \| \le \underbrace{|c^n|}_{\to \infty}\cdot \underbrace{\|T^nx\|}_{\to 0}$$

So the only possible way for $\left( |c^n| \cdot \| T^n x \| \right) \to 0$ is, if $\|c^n|$ will grow to $\infty$ slower than $\| T^n x\|$ grows to $0$.

Is there any special type of contractions, for which this would be true? What additional assumptions must I make?

Note, that $x$ is any arbitrary element from the Hilbert space $H$.

Comment: $Tx=\frac 1 2 x$ on the real line, $c=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The necessary and sufficient condition is that the spectral radius $r(T)$ is less than $1.$ Indeed assume $c^nT^nx\to 0$ for any $x.$ By the uniform boundedness principle the norms $c^nT^n$ are uniformly bounded i.e. $c^n\|T^n|\le m$ for some constant $m.$Thus $$r(T)=\lim \|T^n\|^{1/n}\le c^{-1}<1$$ The converse implication does not require advanced theorems. If $r(T)<1$ then  $a=[r(T)+1]/2$ satisfies $r(T)<a<1.$ Hence there exists $n_0$ such that $$ \|T^n\|^{1/n}\le a,\quad n\ge n_0$$ We get $a^{-n}\|T^n\|\le 1,$ for $n\ge n_0,$ which implies $b^nT^n\to 0$ for $1<b<a^{-1}.$

**Remark** The operator $T$ does not need to be a contraction. Its norm can be larger than $1.$ For example let $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an orthonormal basis and $Te_1=re_2$ and $Te_n=0$ for $n\ge 2.$ Then $T^2=0$ and $\|T\|=r.$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have a question: Would this mean, that if $T$ is a unitary operator, then it wouldn't work, as the spectrum of a unitary operator is contained in $\mathbb{T}$, thus $r(T) = 1$?

Comment: If $T$ is unitary then $\|T^nx\|=\|x\|.$